# Efficient deterministic algorithms of factorizing

Tags: computational-complexity, computability-theory, finite-fields, computer-algebra, computational-number-theory

My question is about efficient deterministic algorithms of factorizing polynomials of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Are there such algorithms that use poly$(n, \log q)$ bit operations?

I know  that this is true if $q$ is a prime number - see the paper of Shoup V . "A new polynomial factorization algorithm and its implementation".

Is it true for an arbitrary finite field?

Comment: Try searching via google.  This will lead you to the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials_over_finite_fields  and to a survey paper by von zur Gathen and Panario,  which tell you what's known.  There is no known deterministic polynomial time algorithm for this which works in every case.

Comment: @MichaelZieve thank you, I was misled by the book "Number-theoretic Algorithms in Cryptography" by Vasilenko where he did not note that $q$ must be prime in the algorithm of Shoup

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev, yes, of course. I have edited my question, I hope now it is clear

Comment: @Alexey: It is still not clear. Perhaps, you meant $\mathbb{Z}_q$, but even if so, $\mathbb{F}_q$ is not the same as $\mathbb{Z}_q$ when $q$ is not prime.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev my question is about finite fields only

Comment: There isn't even an algorithm that is unconditionally proved to factor *quadratics* over large prime fields in polynomial time.  ("Unconditionally" because there *is* such an algorithm under the extended Riemann Hypothesis.)

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies what is the algorithm under $EGRH$?

Comment: Find a quadratic nonresidue $r \ll \log^2(p)$ (if memory serves) 
by trying all candidates.  Once you have a non-square in a finite field 
it's easy to extract square roots.  The existence of a quadratic nonresidue
of size polynomial in $\log p$ is a known consequence of the ERH.
(Not "EGRH": I mean the analogue of Riemann for Dirichlet $L$-series;
here we need the $L$-series associated to the quadratic character $\bmod p$.)